# How to make a Root to get access to the MariaDB server, trough a client app like MysqlWorkbench?

Tags: mariadb, users

I am running a brand new Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine to perform some testes with **MariaDB** AND Nginx AND PHP7.

When I was installing MariaDB (trough apt-get install mariadb-server) I was not asked to set a password for **root** user, like it is when we do install MySql-server.

Then I installed MySql Workbench as a client to MariaDB server.

When I try to connect to the db server as a **root** with no password, I have an error like the picture below:
[image]

As you can see in the picture below, the **root** user has no password, and I have created another user with no password using this syntax: `CREATE USER 'ig2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ''`.
[image]

So now, when I try to to connect the just created user **ig2** with no password I have a warning and a successful connection.
[image]
[image]

So, I sit a password to the root user with this syntax: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123');` and now the root has a encrypted password.

[image]

If I try to connect again with the root and his password 
[image]

And I still have the same connection errror for the root user:
[image]

If I set the same password for the user ig2, using the same syntax used to sit root's password, I can have a successful connection.

And it is weird when I try to connect trough the terminal:
[image]

The root user can connect with or without password.

In resume, I don't know what is happening, and I don't know how to make the root to get access to the server, trough a client application like Workbench.

Does someone can explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672008/cant-login-to-mysql-as-root-anymore) should help you out:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root

[mysql] use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
```

In short, the new version of MariaDB checks to see what the system user is and only allows the actual system user `root` to log in to the DB user `root`. Disabling all plugins disables that functionality.

Comment: Yes, the link you provide sent me to others links that discuss about the same subject, the anonymous connection in MariaDB. So I think there is no answer to the issue for now. I think the best option is create a new user, give it root privileges and use it as a root. It is completelly weird that I still have a Root user that can get access to the server without a password - using terminal but not client aplications. I' ve already ran a mysl_secure_instalation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_secure_installation/ and I still can get access to the server without password.